# How to use SQL CONTAINS or LIKE with multiple arguments

Tags: sql

I'd like to use the SQL LIKE or CONTAINS operator with multiple arguments. Is there a way to do this efficiently, or does each instance of LIKE have to be separated by OR?

```
WHEN postal_zip_code_permanent like ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Y') THEN 'Canada, outside Ontario'
```

Comment: Do you really need **like** operator here. `Like` operator without `wildcards` doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: You're right... I don't really need LIKE. I'm not sure what I was thinking. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your simple case you can use `IN` instead of `LIKE`

```
WHEN postal_zip_code_permanent IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Y') THEN 'Canada, outside Ontario'
```

If you really need `LIKE`, you need to write

```
WHEN postal_zip_code_permanent LIKE 'A%' OR postal_zip_code_permanent LIKE 'B%' THEN ...
```